# What does $\Bbb{C}(X)$ refer to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, field-theory

I have from a book

> (b) Let $E = \Bbb{C}(X)$. Then $\operatorname{Aut}(E / \Bbb{C})$ consists of the maps $X \mapsto \dfrac{aX + b}{cX + d}, ad-bc \neq 0\ldots$

Not sure what $\Bbb{C}(X)$ is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first, what is $\mathbb{C}[X]$?  It is, by definition, the set $\{ a_{0} + a_{1}X + a_{2} X^{2} + a_{3}X^{3} + \dots + a_{n}X^{n} | a_{i} \in \mathbb{C}, n \in \Bbb N \}$.  In other words, it is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb C$ (and it's actually an integral domain).

Now, $\Bbb C(X)$ is the *fractional field* of the integral domain $\mathbb{C}[X]$.  That is, $\Bbb C(X)$ is the set of elements that look like $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}[X]$ and $b \neq 0$.  Of course, we are really talking about equivalence classes (just like in $\mathbb{Q}$, $\frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{6}$, for example).  It's easy to prove that $\mathbb{C}(X)$ satisfies the axioms of a field.  We call it the fractional field of the ring $\Bbb C[X]$ since it's constructed by taking all possible "fractions" made from the elements of $\Bbb C[X]$.

Comment: The set you wrote suggests "Finite polynomials" - is that true?

Comment: @AlecTeal Well, a polynomial by definition has finite degree.  You are right, $\Bbb C[x]$ consists of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb C$, which means they have finite degree (i.e., they are "finite polynomials").  See the wikipedia page for polynomials if you still have doubts: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial

Answer (score 7):

It is the field of rational functions with complex coefficients in one variable. 
It is the quotient field of the ring of polynomials in one variable, that is an element of it is the quotient of two polynomials.

Answer (score 6):

$\mathbb{C}(X)$ is the field of rational functions in the indeterminate $X$ over $\mathbb{C}$. This is the field consisting of all quotients of polynomials in $X$ (with the denominator nonzero) with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3):

$E = \mathbf{C}(X)$ is the fractions field of the domain $\mathbf{C}[X]$, ring of polynomials in the formal variable $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbf{C}$. Every element of $E$ can be written $\frac{P}{Q}$ with $P,Q\in\mathbf{C}[X]$ *coprime* polynomials and $Q\not=0$, which *in this case* means that $P$ and $Q$ have no common roots. The definition is valid for any field $k$ instead of $\mathbf{C}$.